# Laravel Eloquent: how to select datas from a relation in a collection or change their names before being turned into JSON?

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, eloquent

I have been stuck on this for a while even after reading other questions & docs from Laravel. I just can't understand how I can access the datas that are in a collection in nested relations.

**Goal:**
Return a JSON with the values and the keys renamed differently, all of them in a "one level deep" array (example: [{"all the datas I want without anything nested"},{...},{...}] ).

Here is my query and it gives me a collection with exactly all the datas I need but a lot of them are in the nested relationships.

```
$booking_info = Booking::where('photographer_id', '=', $isPhotographer->id)
                        ->orWhere('user_client_id', '=', $user->id)
                        ->with('photographer')
                        ->with('photographer.user')
                        ->with('user')
                        ->with('stypePhotographer', 'shootingType', 'location', 'bookingStatus', 'currency', 'city')
                        ->get();
```

**Question**
How would you do it? For example how do you create that array/JSON with the datas of the relation 'bookingStatus' Quite broad but I have been battling for a while now...

**EDIT:** this is the array / JSON I need: (I will write the datas as if I was calling them in php for understanding)

```
[{"title":"$booking->bookingStatus->status","start":"$booking->booking_date","description":"$booking->shootingType->shooting_type_name", "client_name":"$booking->user->first_name"},{ NEXT BOOKING RESULT FOUND }, { NEXT BOOKING RESULT FOUND }, ...]
```

**EDIT2**
The select I would have used if I had been using join queries:

```
->select('bookings.id as id', 'bookings.booking_reference as reference', 'duration', 'nb_persons', 'photographer_users.username as photographer', 'photographer_addresses.phonenumber as photographer_phone', 'client_addresses.phonenumber as client_phone', 'client_users.first_name as client_first_name', 'bookingstatus_id as status_id','city_name', 'location_name', 'booking_status as description', 'stype_name as title', 'color', 'booking_date as start', 'booking_date as date')
```

Let me know if you need more infos! :)

Comment: And how do you want to store relation in one dimensional array? What about id of main model and relation model? Which one do you want to store in your flat array? What about other same named columns? I think you should think about it and if you decided show what exactly you have and what columns should be.

Comment: Hi @MarcinNabiałek! thanks, just edited the post for you to see what I want to have exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally ended up converting into an array then retrieving all the data I wanted one by one for each booking and pushing them in a new array then converted in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is call the `toArray()` function after `get()`.  Laravel comes with a helper method called `array_dot()` which will flatten your array so that you can use dot notation.

Here's an example.

```
$booking_info = Booking::where('photographer_id', '=', $isPhotographer->id)
                    ->orWhere('user_client_id', '=', $user->id)
                    ->with('photographer')
                    ->with('photographer.user')
                    ->with('user')
                    ->with('stypePhotographer', 'shootingType', 'location', 'bookingStatus', 'currency', 'city')
                    ->get(array('bookings.id as id', 'bookings.booking_reference as reference', 'duration', 'nb_persons', 'photographer_users.username as photographer', 'photographer_addresses.phonenumber as photographer_phone', 'client_addresses.phonenumber as client_phone', 'client_users.first_name as client_first_name', 'bookingstatus_id as status_id','city_name', 'location_name', 'booking_status as description', 'stype_name as title', 'color', 'booking_date as start', 'booking_date as date'))
                    ->toJson();
```

This will give you an array/json with no nesting and take care of the issue of multiple relations having the same column names not being overwritten.

Comment: Good idea but the thing is that I need the bookings to still be separated but not what is inside... Look at my question I added the select I would have used in theory.

Comment: You can still use select with relationships.  Just add them as an array and pass it with the `->get()` function.  I made an edit to my answer.

Comment: Is _ the nomenclature for calling the relationship? Could I do photographer_user_address.phonenumber as ... ?

Comment: No, you can use periods to define nested relationships and commas to define multiple relationships.  So you could do `->with('photographer.user', 'user', stylePhotographer', 'shootingType', 'location', 'bookingStatus', 'currency', 'city')`